# Invalid Object error returned when using SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When trying to `select from 'jREwardToysRUs.dbo.MailDetail_198'` table from jREwardToysRUs DataBase, I am getting the following error:

> Invalid object name 'jREwardToysRUs.dbo.MailDetail_198'

Like below :

```
select top 10 *
from jREwardToysRUs.dbo.MailDetail_198
```

but giving [], the error is gone.Like:

```
select top 10 *
from [jREwardToysRUs.dbo.MailDetail_198]
```

Please suggest. how to remove error while selecting only with table name?

Comment: Tried to read the question, now I am blind.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli And now you can see again! :)

Comment: When quoting objects in SQL Server, you need to quote each object separately. So, when using 3 part naming conventions `DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName` would become `[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]`. If you encapulate the whole thing, the Query analyser would look for a database object literally called `'DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName'` within the database you are currently connected to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for "use" keyword:

```
use [jREwardToysRUs]
go

select top 10 * 
from [dbo].[MailDetail_198]
```

Comment: No the entire jREwardToysRUs.dbo.MailDetail_198 is the table name. So to use this in SQL,enclose them with [Table Name]. Like below:
 select top 10 *
 from [jREwardToysRUs.dbo.MailDetail_198]